# `TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument` when I am passing an argument into it?

Tags: python, typeerror

I am passing an argument into Xz() so I don't understand what this error is pointing to.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @property
    def Xmean(self):
        Xs = 0
        Xcount = 0
        for point in self.data:
            X, Y = point
            Xs += X
            Xcount += 1
        return Xs/Xcount

    @property
    def Xsd(self):
        total_var_X = 0
        varcount = 0
        for point in self.data:
            X, Y = point
            total_var_X += (X-self.Xmean)**2
            varcount += 1
        return total_var_X / varcount

    @property
    def Xz(self, point):
        X, Y = point
        return (X-self.Xmean)/self.Xsd

data1 = Data([(-1,-2), (0,0), (2,1), (4,4), (6,5)])
    
print(data1.Xmean)
print(data1.Xz(data1[0]))
```

1. Why do I get `TypeError: Xz() missing 1 required positional argument: 'point'` from the second print?
2. I only got this error from onlineGDB but when I was experimenting with PyCharm, I didn't any result but also didn't get any error, why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: A `property` shouldn't take an argument.  Just remove `@property`.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove @property also
You must pass an argument to your Xz method but in

```py
print(data1.Xz(data1[0]))
```

you pass a wrong argument to your method. data1 is an object from Data class and not a list. There fore data1[0] is not a correct argument.
type:

```py
print(data1.Xz(data1.data[0]))
```

Comment: I understand the second problem and have updated accordingly.
But I still don't understand the problem with @property, could you explain more?

Comment: What do you think [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) does?

Comment: I think that a property calculate a new attribute for instance and in your class your Xz calculate a value for a tuple out of your class and instance and not related to your instance. Therefor it is not true that you use from it for this purpose

Comment: @AliM Well, this question wasn't for you. :)

Comment: Hi, I'm back  I'm actually not entirely sure. I only self-taught a bit of python and was experimenting with something for practice, then I ran into a problem of a method not changing along with other attributes it's using in calculation if I remember correctly, so my friend taught me to use @property to turn it into an attribute of sort and it worked. I've read a couple of articles but still aren't sure I understand the exact nature of it.